# Подключение к IP камере через opencv python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, камера

Имеется старая IP камера D-link 950, хочу подключится к ней. В мануале и настройках к камере написано, что для подключения через http нужно использовать формат типа `http://IP_Address_of_camera/iMode.asp`. Написал вот такой код

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture('http://admin:pass@IP_Address_of_camera/iMode.asp')
print(capture.read())

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

В итоге выходит ошибка, хотя с более новыми камерами с форматом `video1.mjpg` все работает прекрасно

Ошибка:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-iw3y3ir8\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (142) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-iw3y3ir8\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://admin:micron@10.100.11.60:80/iMode.asp in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/status servers bot/video.py", line 16, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-iw3y3ir8\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

<VideoCapture 0000018DC4263D10>
[tcp @ 0000018dc44e3240] Connection to tcp://10.100.11.60:80 failed: Error number -138 occurred
```

Помогите разобраться как подключатся к камерам с форматом `.asp`

Comment: я не увидел в списке протоколов rtsp, он вообще там есть? судя по описанию оно может данные отдать только через активх.

Comment: Протокол, необходимый для просмотра: ActiveX. т.е. работает только через IE. почитай документацию есть ли там вообще возможность забирать поток в формате mjpeg или rtsp. без этого ты через опенсиви не сможешь получать данные. без танцев с бубном.

Comment: @Yakov Судя по документации камеры, у нее имеется только `.asp`. Вы правы, веб интерфейс у нее работает только в IE

Comment: asp - это расширение веб-страницы. которое только косвенно указывает на язык серверной стороны веб-страницы. в реальности там может быть CGI или PHP в качестве обработчика на стороне сервера. сервер потокового вещания с HTTP транспортом может быть и не связан совсем. если он есть то можно забирать данные с камеры минуя веб-страницу. если его нет вы с помощью опенцв этого делать не сможете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760601/asp-net-ffmpeg-video-conversion-receiving-error-error-number-2-occurred

Comment: https://www.ispyconnect.com/camera/d-link
`http://IPADDRESS/cgi-bin/video.jpg?size=2`

Answer (score 1):

насколько мне известно, вы не можете брать прямой поток с камеры посредством OpenCV, но можно брать snap с камеры (раз в секунду).

```py
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

def get_snap():
    user = 'admin'
    password = 'admin1234'
    link = 'http://<IP>/onvifsnapshot/media_service/snapshot?channel=1&subtype=0'
    # ссылку смотрите для своей камеры
    session = requests.session()
    session.auth = HTTPDigestAuth(user, password)
    photo = session.get(link)
    session.close()
    if photo.ok:
        f = open(file_path, 'wb')
        f.write(photo.content)
        f.close()
    else:
        print('error')
```